# HTML - YouTube videos: "Video Unavailable. Watch on YouTube" error

Tags: html, youtube

I'm new to HTML and testing out the video elements. I can get a local video to work, but when I try to use a video from YouTube (using the embedded element), the player doesn't work. I'm not sure what's going on here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <h1>Video Tests</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Local File - Works</h2>
        <video width = "320" autoplay = "autoplay" height = "240" controls>
        <source src ="C:\Users\Tim\Pictures\Camera Roll\Promise.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag
        </video>
        <br>

        <h2>YouTube Link - Doesn't Load</h2>
        <p>The player says "Video Unavailable. Watch on YouTube".</p>
        <p>Then when you click on it, it takes you to the correct YT video on YT's website.</p><br>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/dUro-rg2Uz8?si=Q-T97-RBw6hqjvxH" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

An image showing the results on the website.